# Elements that are related under an automorphism have the same number of fixpoints in group action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group, $M$ a set and $\alpha: G \times M \to M$ a group action. For $g \in G$, let $\operatorname{Fix}_{\alpha}(g) = \{ m \in M \mid g \cdot_{\alpha} m = m \}$.

It is easily seen that if $g, h \in G$, then $\operatorname{Fix}_{\alpha}(h g h^{-1}) = h \operatorname{Fix}_{\alpha}(g)$, so in particular $|\operatorname{Fix}_{\alpha}(h g h^{-1})| = |\operatorname{Fix}_{\alpha}(g)|$.

Now let $\varphi \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$. Does it hold that $|\operatorname{Fix}_{\alpha}(\varphi(g))| = |\operatorname{Fix}_{\alpha}(g)|$?

Comment: No.  Consider an action of a direct sum of two copies of a group $G$ such that the first copy acts trivially and the second doesn't.  Now look at the automorphism which switches the factors.

Comment: What do you mean by "$h \operatorname{Fix}_{\alpha}(g)$"?

Comment: @citadel I mean $\{ h \cdot_{\alpha}m \mid m \in \operatorname{Fix}_{\alpha}(g)\}$

Comment: I've come to $\operatorname{Fix}(h^{}gh^{-1})=$  $\{m\in M\mid h^{-1}\cdot m\in\operatorname{Fix}(g)\}$, which still I don't see how it matches yours. But I'm too in a hurry now.

Comment: @citadel Yes, and then you have for $m \in M$ with $h^{-1} \cdot_{\alpha} m \in \operatorname{Fix}_{\alpha}(g)$ that $m = h \cdot_{\alpha} (h^{-1} \cdot_{\alpha} m)$, so $m \in h \operatorname{Fix}_{\alpha}(g)$.

Comment: @citadel In the other direction, given $h \cdot_{\alpha} m$ with $m \in \operatorname{Fix}_{\alpha}(g)$, we see that $h^{-1} \cdot_{\alpha} (h \cdot_{\alpha} m) = m$, so $h \cdot_{\alpha} m \in \operatorname{Fix}_{\alpha}(h g h^{-1})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on @lulu's comment:

Consider a nontrivial action $\alpha: G \times M \to M$, meaning that $\exists g_0 \in G, m_0 \in M : g_0 \cdot_{\alpha} m_0 \neq m_0$. Now let $\beta: (G \times G) \times M \to M, (g_1, g_2) \cdot_{\beta} m = g_2 \cdot_{\alpha} m$. Then we have $\operatorname{Fix}_{\beta}(g_0, e) = M$, but $\operatorname{Fix}_{\beta}(e, g_0) \neq M$ because $m_0 \notin \operatorname{Fix}_{\beta}(e, g_0)$. However, $(g_0, e)$ and $(e, g_0)$ are related by the automorphism of $G \times G$ swapping the two factors.